# many codecs are missing in ffmpeg 4.0.2,what to do about it?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I recently built ffmpeg 4.0.2 as shared libraries for including into android project using tutorial this tutorial:[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@karthikcodes1999/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-b988326f16f2)

build was successful but my libs as missing several codecs such as msvideo1,xanwc4,...

I checked the c files inside libavcodec folder file inside ffmpeg4.0.2 folder couldn't find many codec formats.
For example the libavcodec folder contains file named xan.c which contains function for xan,xanwc3 but not xanwc4.
But in libvcodec/xxan.c found xanwc4 codec but still avcodec_open2() returns -22.
avcodec_open2() is returning -22 for every codec.

can anyone help me figure out how to make my .apk to work on every codec and formats?what to do about missing codecs?

c-sourcecode is here:

```
const char *name;
int i,videostream;
name= (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, argv_,0);
AVFormatContext *pFormatctx=NULL;
if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatctx,name,NULL,NULL)!=0){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"a");
}
if(pFormatctx==NULL){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"b");
}
if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatctx,NULL)<0){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"c");
}
av_dump_format(pFormatctx, 0, name, 0);
videostream=-1;
AVCodecContext *pCodecCtxOrig = NULL;
AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
for (i==0;i<pFormatctx->nb_streams;i++){
    if((pFormatctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type)==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
        videostream=i;
        break;
    }
}
if(videostream==-1){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"d");
}
pCodecCtxOrig=pFormatctx->streams[videostream]->codecpar;
AVCodec *pCodec = NULL;
pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
if(pCodec==NULL){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"e");
}
pCodecCtx=avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
if((avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecCtx,pCodecCtxOrig))!=0){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"f");
}
if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx,pCodec,NULL)<0){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"g");
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Rebuild with the codecs you want.  Make sure to call configure to see what the options are.

Comment: The pCodec->id and pCodecCtxOrig->codecid were same and pCodecCtx->codecid was different.Thought that avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecCtx,pCodecCtxOrig) was faulty as it doesn't copy the context but copies only parameters.I replaced pCodecCtxOrig with pCodecCtx.Everything working fine now including codecs.

Comment: You can provide your solution as an answer instead of a comment.